# how to pass European date as parameter to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

Using SQL Server 2012, and the new date type (not dateTime) I created the next procedure:

```
CREATE PROC Test(@StartDate date ,@EndDate date)    
AS    
DECLARE @Temp TABLE([ID] int, [Date] date)    
INSERT INTO @Temp SELECT 1, CONVERT(date,'31/12/2012',103)    
INSERT INTO @Temp SELECT 2, CONVERT(date,'01/10/2012',103)    
INSERT INTO @Temp SELECT 3, CONVERT(date,'01/01/2012',103)    
SELECT * FROM @Temp WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

When I run this stored procedure I get the next error indicating the date format of the parameter:

```
Incorrect syntax near '/'.
```

Please what should be done ?

Comment: Perhaps add the bit of SQL where you execute the stored procedure

Comment: @Andomar please explain more.

Comment: Sure, this is what I meant: edit your question and add the way you call the stored procedure.  That is in addition to the sp definition and the error message

Comment: Seeing as start and end dates are passed as dates, your question makes no sense. If you were passing them in as strings it would, but then the answer would have been stop doing that!

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, how it should be done instead please?

Comment: Your C# code should be declaring date/time parameters. You shouldn't be building a string to execute.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I'll pass these parameters from DateTimePicker controls.

Comment: @Andomar, thank you for your reply. I right clicked on the stored procedure to execute it then when I entered the parameter in the 'dd/MM/yyyy' I got the error message, then when I did it as Aaron advised: 'yyyyMMdd' it worked.. Also: EXEC dbo.Test StartDate = '2012/01/01', EndDate = '2012/12/31'; Also works so the slashes are Ok.

Comment: The error message doesn't fit. It looks like it is complaining about a syntax error (?). It should say something like "invalid date".

Comment: @usr if the original string was `EXEC Test 2012/01/01` without string delimiters, SQL Server would complain about a syntax error because you can't evaluate expressions there.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I didn't see your answer in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, your date shouldn't have a `/` in it. But it also needs to be enclosed in quotes. Try:

```
EXEC dbo.Test @StartDate = '20120101', @EndDate = '20120131';
```

The reason it needs to be enclosed in quotes is, if you don't use quotes, your "date" is interpreted as a mathematical expression, e.g.:

```
01/01/2012 = 1 divided by 1 divided by 2012
```

The reason your date shouldn't have a `/` in it is because `m/d/y` and `d/m/y` are unsafe formats that can be interpreted differently depending on language and other settings.

And finally, if you are calling this procedure from C#, why are you passing strings and not properly typed parameters?

Comment: Dateformat 103 is British/French `dd/mm/yyyy`, so the slashes seem ok

Comment: @Andomar do you have insight into the problem that isn't in the question?

Comment: The slashes are okay, but they are only required because the STRING literals are in dd/mm/yyyy format. Without the style argument this would work on a european server. Image if one our colonial brethren took this code on. They's have to be constantly confused or go through and find every example of this and switch it to MM/DD/YYYY, follow Mt Bertrand's advice and it work everywhere with no confusion and no extra work.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, how to use typed parameters from C# WinForm DateTimePicker, please ?

Comment: @AlphaBird I suggest you post that as a different question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Ok I'll do that ASAP.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Please take a look at **[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927502/passing-date-parameter-from-c-sharp-winform-to-sql-stored-procedure/11927726#11927726](this)**