# Passing Date parameter from C# WinForm to SQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures, type-conversion

I have a form with 2 `dateTimePicker` controls (`dtpStart` and `dtpEnd`), a button, and a `datagridview` to show results. The `datagridview` is bound to a `bindingSource` control.

I want to pass two `date` parameters from the `dateTimePicker` controls to the stored procedure in order to return the required scope on my datagridview.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[ProcTest](@StartDate date, @EndDate date)
AS
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE ModifiedDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

My C# code is:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dc = new NorthwindDataContext();

        var Qry = dc.ProcTest(dtpStart.Value, dtpEnd.Value);
        bindingSource1.DataSource = Qry;
    }
```

When I run the code above I receive nothing on my datagrid, the `dtpEnd.value` shows: `13/08/2012 02:15:29`, I assume that this is a conversion issue since I use `date` type in my stored procedure and the `datetimepicker` value is a `dateTime` type.

Please, how to resolve this ?

Comment: Try to pass date part only - dtpStart.Value.Date

Comment: @AVD, dtpStart.Value.Date shows 13/08/2012 00:00:00 which doesn't work, and I think that to get my code to work I'll need that my SP receives something like this: '2012/08/13'.

Comment: I think a part of the solution is to use ToShortDateString() like this: dtpStart.Value.ToShortDateString() returns 13/08/2012, the query need it at this format: '2012/08/13' or '20120813'

Comment: Try to convert result to `List<T>` - dataGridView1.DataSource=res.ToList();

Comment: @AVD, this seems to be a solution, I used your proposal successfuly in the SP, and dtpStart.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") returned the right format, but still cannot receive data in my datagrid, need to verify datagrid binding...  I have made some google search, we have here a culture matter, so it is also possible to keep date type for the parameters and use dtpStart.Value.ToUniversalTime()

Comment: I don't think that there was problem with `Date` params. My guess is that your code uses local database from (its copy) at bin/debug and it is empty.

Comment: @AVD, Please how to check that ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to retrieve the results of your query, e.g.:

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = Qry.ToList();
```

I don't think the issue is with the Date parameter at all. That's supported according to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your advice, nothing changed when tried bindingSource1.DataSource = Qry.ToList();

Comment: @AlphaBird - Have you tried hard-coding the date parameters, to ensure that your stored procedure is actually returning something?

Comment: After removing parameters from SP and running the program, I found that the problem was that the bindingsource was not bound at design time to the SP result, so I created a new datasource object pointing to the result of the SP and then the datagrid shown data. And there is no need to add .ToList() to the query.

Comment: @AlphaBird - I'm sorry ToList() wasn't required after all. The examples I'd seen use it, so I thought that was the issue. It's great that the project is all fixed now, though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
var Qry = dc.ProcTest(dtpStart.Value, dtpEnd.Value);
```

use this and check if your problem get solved.

```
var Qry = dc.ProcTest(dtpStart.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), dtpEnd.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
```

Comment: No overload for method 'ToString'.

Comment: k,I have edited the code, and posted just below. just check this also.

var Qry = dc.ProcTest(Convert.ToDateTime(dtpStart).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), Convert.ToDateTime(dtpEnd).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link provided by Dave R.:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx I found out that my code could work without any modification. So I searched the error first by removing parameters from SP, then I found that I had to create a new **datasource object pointing to the result of the SP**, and to **bind it at design time** to the datagridview. Now the datagrid shows data and parameters are working.

Sorry Guys, I had to verify that before posting my question, but I was very confused about Date parameters usage.

so I Keep the code as it is in the initial question:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dc = new NorthwindDataContext();

    var Qry = dc.ProcTest(dtpStart.Value, dtpEnd.Value);
    bindingSource1.DataSource = Qry;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I beleive you need to send the date, not the value of your datetime picker.

Basically, change this line:

```
var Qry = dc.ProcTest(dtpStart.Value, dtpEnd.Value);
```

To read:

```
var Qry = dc.ProcTest(dtpStart.SelectedDate.Value, dtpEnd.SelectedDate.Value);
```

If that still doesn't work I would try:

```
var Qry = dc.ProcTest(dtpStart.SelectedDate.Value.Date, dtpEnd.SelectedDate.Value.Date);
```

Comment: If you're going to downvote, could you please at least explain why?

Comment: Someone have downvoted I think because SelectedDate is not a property of dateTimePicker control.